# Swipe over table in mobile browser

Tags: mobile, browser, dart

I and my teammate are writing the game "Battlecity" in dart for mobile browser. The problem is with swipes for tank direction(left to right, right to left, etc) in mobile browser. It works with a great delation(and for some reasond doesn't works in Chrome-Browser). 
You can see the problem better, if you start the game on your mobile device(just open link with game: https://javajunikorn.github.io/BattleCity/build/web/html/test.html)
Interesting thing is, that the problem exists only on swipes over gamefield(in our case it's 27*27 html table). If we're swiping out of gamefeeld, than it works great.

Here is code of our Controller:

```
class Direction{


  Point first, last;
  Game game;

  void startListening(){


    window.onTouchStart.listen((ev) {
      last = null;
      first = ev.touches.first.client;
    });

    window.onTouchMove.listen((ev){
      last = ev.touches.first.client;
    });

    window.onTouchEnd.listen((ev) {
      if(last == null || first.distanceTo(last) < 20)
        game.player.shoot();
      else {
        Point d = first - last;
        if(d.x.abs() > d.y.abs()){
          //Waagerecht
          if( first.x > last.x){
            //links
            game.player.changeDirection(Directions.left);
          }
          else{
            //rechts
            game.player.changeDirection(Directions.right);
          }
        }
        else{
          //Senkrecht
          if(first.y > last.y){
            //Up
            game.player.changeDirection(Directions.up);
          }
          else{
            //Down
            game.player.changeDirection(Directions.down);

          }
        }
      }
    });


    window.onKeyPress.listen((k) {
      //Shoot
      if(k.which == 32) { //spacebar
        game.player.shoot();
      }
      //Up
      if(k.which == 119 || k.keyCode == KeyCode.UP){
        game.player.changeDirection(Directions.up);
      }
      //Down
      if(k.which == 115 || k.keyCode == KeyCode.DOWN){
        game.player.changeDirection(Directions.down);
      }
      //Left
      if(k.which == 97 || k.keyCode == KeyCode.LEFT){
        game.player.changeDirection(Directions.left);
      }
      //Right
      if(k.which == 100 || k.keyCode == KeyCode.RIGHT){
        game.player.changeDirection(Directions.right);
      }
    });

  }

}
```